# Vue-Project is deploying but not displaying on Git Hub pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, github-pages, vite

I have followed all the tutorials I could online but I cannot get a test Vite-Project (React based) to run on Github pages. All I get is a blank screen a warning stating Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (). Here is a link to the repository - https://github.com/PortDaveA/vite-project. Here is a link to the github page (https://portdavea.github.io/vite-project/). I have tried to find other Vite project pages and many of them have similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must check your vite.config.js file.
In base property you should write the url of your repository in github.
Like in this screenshot:
[image]

Also you can read this article or Vite docs. Here the links
https://dev.to/shashannkbawa/deploying-vite-app-to-github-pages-3ane
https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy.html

Comment: I have already done that.